# Counting the number of rows based on the value of N number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by, count

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
A        100     100
A         0       0
A         0      100
B        100      0
C        100     100
C        100     100
```

I want to count the number of rows with 100 (or any other values greater than zero) based on `A B` and `C`

which will result to this:

```
    Col2_counts   Col3_counts
A       1           2
B       1           0
C       2           2
```

so I can calculate the total percentage of `A B C` in `Col2` and `Col3` etc.

I tried `df.groupby(['Col1', 'Col 2', 'Col3']).transform ('count')`, but it doesn't give me the desired result.

Comment: What are your counting exactly? `count` is for counting rows, regardless of their value. It seems like (but you said nothing, we have to reverse engineer that) you are counting non-0 aka 100 values. In which case, `df.groupby('col1').sum()/100` seems to be what you are looking for. But are all the values either 0 or 100? You didn't say.

Comment: @chrslg as shown in the desired result, the rows with 100. but let me edit it for clarification. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Well, it wasn't shown in the desired result. It could have been has well the rows with non-0 values. Or the rows with values over 50. All your examples shows only either 0 or 100 value, but, all those assumption match equally the example, but are not equivalent, unless you state that values can only be 0 or 100. There again, you could replay "yes, they can be only 0 or 100, as shown", but, well, firstly, specification usually don't take the form of a guessing game, and secondly, it would be quite strange: it would be a binary value; usually we use booleans for that, not 0 and 100.

Comment: And the answer you accepted doesn't count the rows with 100, but the rows with >0 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.set_index('Col1').gt(0).groupby(level=0).sum()
```

output:

```
        Col2    Col3
Col1        
A       1       2
B       1       0
C       2       2
```

Comment: Although this answer was accepted, it could probably benefit from some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The following block produces your expected output:

```py
(
    df
    .set_index("Col1")
    .eq(100)
    .groupby("Col1")
    .sum()
    .add_suffix("_counts")
)
```

As chrslg pointed out, Panda Kim's answer evaluates rows > 0 instead of rows == 100. Also, you can add the `"_counts"` suffix at the end to get the column names from your example.

Here's a the step-by-step explanation of each operation:

1. Set `"Col1"` as the DataFrame's index.
2. Evaluate if cells are equal (`eq`) to 100.

   ```
         Col2    Col3
   Col1        
   A     True    True
   A     False   False
   A     False   True
   B     True    False
   C     True    True
   C     True    True
   ```
3. Group by the `"Col1"` index and count `True` values. Using the `sum` operation works because it converts `True` to 1 and `False` to 0.
4. Add a `"_counts"` suffix to all columns.

   ```
         Col2_counts   Col3_counts
   Col1        
   A         1              2
   B         1              0
   C         2              2
   ```